# html-docs.js generated doc is blank

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am new to node js. I am learning express js. I want to create the word file form the html content. I am using **html-docs-js**. Word is generated in folder . But word did not have any content. Word is blank .

**My code**

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
 var HtmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var html = '<p>My content<p>';

 var docx = HtmlDocx.asBlob(html);
 fs.writeFile('myword.docx',docx, function (err){
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('done');
 });

 res.send('File Generated in Folder');
```

});

After I use the code

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
var HtmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
var fs = require('fs');
var html = '<p>My content<p>';

var docx = HtmlDocx.asBlob(html);
fs.writeFile('myword.docx',docx, function (err){
    console.log('first');
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log('done');
res.send('File Generated in Folder');
console.log('last');
});
});
```

print in console correctly . but the file is still blank.

**Finally I got solution while using the following code . It working nice for me.**

```
  fs.readFile('./index.ejs', 'utf-8', function(err, html) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // var docx = htmlDocx.asBlob(html);
    fs.writeFile('newgenword.txt', html, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else{
            console.log("Docx has been created");
        }
    });
  });
```

This may be useful for someone..

Comment: you get the "done" printed in the console ?

Comment: No not printed in console

Comment: so you get some error printed instead ?

Comment: Some warning is printed "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:3000/extractword/"."

Comment: No error is printed code executed and blank file generated. Nothing printed in console

Comment: router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
var HtmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
var fs = require('fs');
var html = '<p>My content<p>';

var docx = HtmlDocx.asBlob(html);
fs.writeFile('myword.docx',docx, function (err){
    console.log('first');
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log('done');
res.send('File Generated in Folder');
console.log('last');
});
});

Comment: Now done is printed in console . But docx file is empty / blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs.readFile('./index.ejs', 'utf-8', function(err, html) {
    if (err) throw err;

```
// var docx = htmlDocx.asBlob(html);
fs.writeFile('newgenword.txt', html, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
        console.log("Docx has been created");
    }
});
```

});